# How can i set column length in grid according to number of items in my database?

Tags: html, laravel, grid

I'm trying to display banners on my laravel project from the database in a grid. But the issue is that if i have 1 item in my database i want my grid class to be col-12 and if there are more than 1 items in my database i want class to be col-6.

```
@if($status == 1)
<div style="background: {{$color}};">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        @foreach($data['banners'] as $banner )
        @if($banner->status==1)
        <div class="col-6 p-1">
                <div style="background-image:url(assets/images/{{$banner->bannerImage}});background-size: cover;height:55vh" class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                        <div class="container bannertext text-wrap">
                            <h1 class="">{{$banner->heading}}</h1>
                            <h3 class="">{{$banner->subHeading}}</h3>
                            <p class="lead">{{$banner->description}}</p>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        @endif
        @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Check if count in database is more than 1 then use col-6 snippet else use col-12 snippet.

```
@if(count($data['bannercount'])>1)

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($data['banners'] as $banner )
        <div class="col-6">
            <div style="background-image:url(assets/images/{{$banner->bannerImage}});"
                class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                    <div class="container bannertext text-wrap">
                        <h1 class="">{{$banner->heading}}</h1>
                        <h3 class="">{{$banner->subHeading}}</h3>
                    <p class="lead">{{$banner->description}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
@else 
<div class="row">
    @foreach($data['banners'] as $banner )
    <div class="col-12">
        <div style="background-image:url(assets/images/{{$banner->bannerImage}});"
             class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
            <div class="container bannertext text-wrap">
                <h1 class="">{{$banner->heading}}</h1>
                <h3 class="">{{$banner->subHeading}}</h3>
                <p class="lead">{{$banner->description}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif
```